# An extension for auto complete of css in html

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm searching for an auto-complete extension for my web projects.

For example:

I created the class `.menu` in a css or scss file.

In my html code when typing `class="m"` I want the `menu` suggestion to appear.

Is there an extension for this in vs code?

Comment: auto complete for input text element or what ? Can you be more specific

Comment: Yes, I can. An auto complete for text inputs.  It must be able to search among the different files I have in my project to give me suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [HTML CSS Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css) extension.

> Visual Studio Code CSS Support for HTML Documents
>
> Missing CSS support for HTML documents.
>
> Features

- > Class attribute completion.
  >
  > Id attribute completion.
  >
  > Supports Zen
  >
  > Coding completion for class and id attributes.
  >
  > Scans workspace folder for css and scss files.
  >
  > Supports remote css files.
  >
  > Uses vscode-css-languageservice.